# Android studio не загружает приложение на устройство

Tags: java, android, android-studio

При попытке запустить приложение из студии, она выдаёт стену текста, в котором иногда появляются строки типа

```
`Could not find class 'имя_класса', referenced from method com.example.app.MainActivity.access$super`
```

Во многих местах лога, в разных классах не удаётся найти этот `access$super`. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: пишут, что это [нормально](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792884/many-error-messages-after-updating-gradle-plugin-for-android-to-2-0-0#comment61160106_36792884) - vm сообщает, что не может найти какие-то классы и методы из более нового api. В качестве решения предлагают фильтровать вывод logcat либо откатываться на старый gradle.

Comment: Опишите детальнее